# MySQL COUNT with WHERE and HAVING and ORDER BY in the same query

Tags: mysql, count, where-clause, having

I am running a MySQL query -

```
SELECT
u.userid, u.lastopen, 
r.auto_renew_status, r.product_id, r.is_trial_period, 
(SELECT count(apd.id) FROM apple_purchase_details as apd 
  WHERE apd.id = u.userid 
  GROUP BY u.userid 
  HAVING  count(apd.id) < 5 
) as total
FROM users as u, receipt as r 
WHERE u.userid = r.id and r.is_trial_period = 'false' and r.auto_renew_status = 0
```

The query is working fine, But it is returning `NULL` where total is greater than 5.

Also when I try to add `ORDER BY` clause on `u.lastopen` it takes too long to load. I have already indexed `lastopen` in `users` table.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: so what you want instead of `NULL`?

Comment: @BhargavChudasama, I don't want to show the rows where the count is greater than 5 or NULL, show me rows with the count less than 5 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's returning `NULL` where `total` is greater than 5, becuase you specified so with `HAVING count(apd.id) < 5`, which means that subquery will return **nothing** when it's bigger than 5, resulting in `NULL` value for that particular row.

If you don't want that behaviour, delete `HAVING` constraint in subquery.

This query retrieves data from multiple tables, so index on `lastopen` in `users` won't help much. I would create indexes on columns that are used in `JOIN` `ON` clause.

**UPDATE**

To get desired result, try:

```
SELECT
u.userid, u.lastopen, 
r.auto_renew_status, r.product_id, r.is_trial_period, 
FROM users as u
JOIN receipt as r ON u.userid = r.id
JOIN (
    SELECT id, count(apd.id) FROM apple_purchase_details
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING apd.id > 5
) as apd ON apd.id = u.userid
WHERE r.is_trial_period = 'false' and r.auto_renew_status = 0
```

Comment: I want to show the rows with `count < 5` only, that's why I am using `HAVING`

Comment: Perfect!! It is giving me accurate data, works well with `ORDER BY`, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think calculating the count before the main query and saving it in a temp table will help the efficiency, as well as using inner join keyword. Please try the query below. Instead of 0, you can set what you prefer instead of NULL:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (SELECT count(apd.id) as Total
                           FROM apple_purchase_details as apd 
                           INNER JOIN users as u on u.userid = apd.id 
                           GROUP BY u.userid 
                           HAVING  count(apd.id) < 5);

SELECT
u.userid, u.lastopen, r.auto_renew_status, r.product_id, r.is_trial_period, 
(case when (select Total from t1) is null then 0 else (Select Total from t1) end) as total
FROM users as u, receipt as r 
INNER JOIN receipt as r on  r.id = u.userid and r.is_trial_period = 'false' and r.auto_renew_status = 0
ORDER BY u.lastopen
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting null because your sub query returns null when appid is greater than or equal to 5. And if you don't want null use conditional CASE..WHEN..END to replace null with some desired value.